# Generating hard to guess session tokens

Tags: security, common-lisp

Does this code create sufficiently hard-to-guess session tokens, assuming the server and client are communicating over HTTPS?

**Take 2** *(thanks to [this crypto.SE answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11098/1674))*:

```
(ql:quickload (list :ironclad :cl-base64))

(let ((prng (ironclad:make-prng :fortuna)))
  (defun new-session-token ()
    (cl-base64:usb8-array-to-base64-string
     (ironclad:random-data 32 prng) :uri t)))
```

*As an additional note, the previous version was using the incorrect encryption mode (`ecb`, instead of `ctr` which is preferable for this task), and using an insecure method of generating random keys (`(sha256 rand)`).*

If not, what else is required for that goal, and why?

Are there attacks I should be worried about other than guessing and sniffing session tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't give enough information about exactly what you want to do to know if this might work in your case.  The most important answer is simple though:  "don't do that; use a web framework instead".  Session management should almost always be done in the standard way of your framework; then you won't have to do anything other than check if your framework thinks your user is authenticated.

Let's now look at the specifics of the code.  You have used a cryptographic PRNG.  That should be fine.  You used 32 bytes = 256 bits of random data.  This should be no problem (128 bits is normally enough against brute force attack; 256 is overkill, which is likely good in this case)  your main fears should probably be seeding and leaking bits.

Seeding: the PRNG documentation says that if you don't give a random seed the PRNG will be unseeded.  In real life it seems that it actually does get seeded from /dev/random.  I deeply don't like this and would probably seed it explicitly.  Better would be discuss with the author and send a patch to the documentation for the library so that it promises to do what it actually does.  I don't have an OS without /dev/random to test on, but I think your function simply won't work there (which is good because it's safe).

Leaking bits1:  If the attacker can find a situation where response time depends on the contents there might be a problem (e.g. force regeneration of the session).  Looking up about timing attacks on Ironclad I don't think it's resistant (see e.g. https://www.mail-archive.com/pro@common-lisp.net/msg00977.html).  You need to check or protect against this.  If the contents of the message are true then you should probably switch to a better library such as LibreSSL when it comes out (possibly GNU TLS?).  If someone attempts to use the function on e.g. Windows I would simply exit with a warning.

Leaking bits2: your output is constant size but includes some special characters. If the attacker can find a situation where your message length depends on the authentication token then you have a problem.  Using Base64 encoding (a second time) should be fine.  Using maximal HTML encoding for your tokens will not be (n.b. normal HTML would be fine; but some encoders go too far).

Leaking bits3: Going further, there are standard attacks against SSL/TLS which I think you should consider; BEAST, CRIME and BREACH which leak bits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#CRIME_and_BREACH_attacks.  Increasing the size of your random token beyond 256 bits might marginally protect against such things.  However "In the current form, the exploit uses JavaScript and needs 6 requests to extract one byte of data" (https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2012/09/14/crime-information-leakage-attack-against-ssltls) so I think you may find that effort would be better invested in turning off compression on all sites and user web browsers.  Personally I would go for 384 bytes just to be more conservative than the rest ;-)

Summary: probably your function is basically the same one used in many frameworks.  Because of the risk of timing attacks and bit leakage I wouldn't personally want to release it for public use until I understood the whole surrounding situation of usage much better than I currently do.

(edited lots since I misread bytes as bits in the first response)

Comment: That's 32 bytes, not bits. Does your assertion that it's too small still hold? If so, how big would it have to be to provide sufficient security? If there's a non-trivial decision function, could you at least outline it in the abstract? What kinds of specifics do you need to know in order to decide whether a session token is hard enough to guess? How would a framework implement this procedure?

Comment: Hmm..  I did misread the bits vs. bytes. (evil editor keeps closing the comment ... hmm).  The "golden" number you are normally aiming for is **bigger** than 128 bits.  That's standard.  AES is e.g. 256 bits, which is reasonable.  The basic point is that we don't think it's reasonable to brute force a number which is much bigger than that.  Then the question is;  does your function or use reduce that number by providing a way to cheat when guessing.  E.g. RSA functions do and for those you need numbers **bigger** than 1024 bits.  I will add a bit about how frameworks work to the answer.